# css pie not working on field elements only

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css3pie

I'm using ie8, don't know about other versions.
I'm using pie all over the place and it generally works ok.  However, all my form input elements have a box shadow and border radius, and no border (pretty much all the styles for it).  In FF/Safari/Chrome all is well, but in IE, the forms lack their box-shadow.

I've also custom-styled my select dropdown fields using this (in coffeescript)

```
$.fn.extend customStyle: (options) ->
  if not $.browser.msie or ($.browser.msie and $.browser.version > 6)
    @each ->
      currentSelected = $(this).find(":selected")
      $(this).after('<span class="customStyleSelectBox"><span class="customStyleSelectBoxInner">' + currentSelected.text() + '</span></span>').css 
        position: 'absolute'
        opacity: 0
        fontSize: $(this).next().css("font-size")

      selectBoxSpan = $(this).next()
      selectBoxWidth = parseInt($(this).width()) - parseInt(selectBoxSpan.css("padding-left")) - parseInt(selectBoxSpan.css("padding-right"))
      selectBoxSpanInner = selectBoxSpan.find(":first-child")
      selectBoxSpan.css display: "inline-block"
      selectBoxSpanInner.css 
        width: selectBoxWidth
        display: "inline-block"

      selectBoxHeight = parseInt(selectBoxSpan.height()) + parseInt(selectBoxSpan.css("padding-top")) + parseInt(selectBoxSpan.css("padding-bottom"))
      $(this).height(selectBoxHeight).change ->
        selectBoxSpanInner.text($(this).find(":selected").text()).parent().addClass "changed"
```

and calling   `$('select').customStyle()`.  Essentially it appends a styled `span` below the original `<select>` that will be the new menu style, while still using the original `<options>`, while hiding the original `select` via opacity.

These are my sass styles

```
.customStyleSelectBox 
  +border-radius(4px)
  +box-shadow(0 1px 1px silver inset)
  +pie /*adds pie.htc behavior */
  position: relative
  z-index: 0
  width: 70px
  background-color: white
  color: #333
  font-size: 12px
  padding: 7px
```

This was working in IE before (at least the `<select>` was styled correctly and was actually showing up), but now it's not (now a bunch of field silhouettes that are completely white, melding into each other and into the next input field, not sure what changed.  And anyway if it worked the z-index/positioning makes it so that nothing dropdowns when you click it.

Does anyone have a solution for the select dropdowns with custom styles, and the no box shadow problem?  Thanks!

Comment: IE8 does not support the border-radius, next to that you have to provide some code to get help.. or http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: pretty sure I mentioned css pie in the header, and in the first couple sentences.

Comment: I've got a feeling that CSS3 PIE can't apply a lot of its magic to form elements. Don't take my word on it though.

Comment: it works, it just is not working correctly because it is hidden behind other elements or something.

Answer (score 0):

apply "position: relative;" to the affected input fields.